# How to override the work directory (docker) in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

When I use a prebuilt Docker image the Github Actions by default set's the work directory to `--workdir /github/workspace`. Is it possible to change this value?

`/usr/bin/docker run --name sshnirozap_action_b3f54a --label 2e4e3a --workdir /github/workspace  sshniro/zap_action zap-baseline.py -t https://www.example.com`

[image]